# Web page is not showing up?

Tags: caching

Right now I uploaded my web page online, and in google chrome I can see it, but on other browsers I see the default page that it had from the web host! what could be wrong here? this has got to do something with the cache?

Comment: Yes, you have tryed to delete your cache?

Comment: what is the web address so we can test it too?

Comment: this is the site: http://www.juve-news.com it worked before now its not working even with google chrome! I dont understand what happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it could have. Do Ctrl-F5, that will refresh the page bypassing the cache in many browsers.